# Fast API Admin getting 404 not able to route

Tags: python, fastapi

I was trying to integrate fast API admin but I am always getting a 404 error
I am follwing this github [repository](https://github.com/fastapi-admin/fastapi-admin)

here is my code

```
from fastapi_admin.app import app as admin_app
from tortoise.contrib.fastapi import register_tortoise
from config.db import init_db, TORTOISE_ORM
from config.endpoints import api_router
from config.settings import settings
app = FastAPI(title=settings.PROJECT_NAME)


register_tortoise(app, config=TORTOISE_ORM, generate_schemas=True)
@app.on_event("startup")
async def startup():
    init_db(app)

# routers
app.include_router(api_router)

# Mount admin url
app.mount("/admin", admin_app.router)
```

I tried all way but still i cant find a way to use fast api admin as we do like in django admin any help will be useful

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: Which URL are you trying to access?

Comment: I am getting 404 details not found error

Comment: @MatsLindh i am trying to access localhost:8000/admin